# "rugarch"-package: Inconsistent output of p-values and t-values

Tags: r, time-series, garch, armax

I am using the "rugarch"-package to estimate the impact of two exegonous variables on a commodity price.
Now I found that the p-values and t-values seem to be very unrealistic in some cases. For example, when changing the model specification from ARMA(8,1)-GARCH to ARMA(8,3)-GARCH, most t-values will reach four-digit values, while most of them were below 10 before.

To me this seems to be very odd and I think that there must be some sort of mistake in the underlying calculations. Additionally, almost all p-values are suddenly 0.0000, which does not make sense to me.

I have tried to scale the values differently (as Alexios Ghalanos recommended to do so in a Blog article) in order to be of a similar magnitude, but this only helps to a certain extend(if I hadn't done so, t-values were already that high in the ARMA(8,1)-GARCH-model. I know that I use lots of regressors, but I need these autoregressive regressors in order for the residuals not to be autoregressive.

Do you have any ideas on how I could fix this problem? Or do you think there is no problem?

I very much appreciate your help!

*Below I print the output and code for both specifications:*

**ARMA(8,3)-GARCH(1,1):**

[image: ARMA(8,3)-GARCH(1,1)]

**ARMA(8,1)-GARCH(1,1):**

[image: ARMA(8,1)-GARCH(1,1)]

```
for_model1 = ts$y

for_model2 = matrix(ts$x1, nrow = length(ts$x1), ncol = 1)

for_model4.1 = matrix(ts$x2, nrow = length(ts$x2), ncol = 1)

for_model4 = cbind(for_model2,for_model4.1)
```

**ARMA(8,1)-GARCH(1,1):**

```
xspec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH",                             garchOrder = c(1, 1), 
                                          submodel = NULL, 
                                          external.regressors = for_model4, 
                                          variance.targeting = FALSE), 

                    mean.model     = list(armaOrder = c(8, 1), include.mean = FALSE, external.regressors = for_model4),
                    distribution.model = "nig")




arma81garch = ugarchfit(spec = xspec, data = for_model1, solver.control = list(trace=0))
```

**ARMA(8,3)-GARCH(1,1):**

```
xspec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH",                             garchOrder = c(1, 1), 
                                          submodel = NULL, 
                                          external.regressors = for_model4, 
                                          variance.targeting = FALSE), 

                    mean.model     = list(armaOrder = c(8, 3), include.mean = FALSE, external.regressors = for_model4),
                    distribution.model = "nig")




arma83garch = ugarchfit(spec = xspec, data = for_model1, solver.control = list(trace=0))
```

Comment: Anecdotal evidence from my own experience: it is enough to switch from ARMA(0,0) to ARMA(1,0) and the estimation becomes pretty unstable. Going for ARMA(1,1) makes things worse. And you have ARMA(8,3)... Try a rolling window within your original data and see how much the coefficients vary across the windows. There is apparently a lack of a built-in stability feature in `rugarch` that would prevent nearly-cancelling AR and MA terms, something that is implemented in the `Arima` and `auto.arima` functions of the `forecast` package. Are the residuals from simpler models really that autocorrelated?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I realized that this problem primarily arises when combining AR and MA terms. So I instead build a SAR(p)(P)[s]-GARCH(1,1) model, which seems to be both stable in many specification. Why is the `rugarch` package then so popular if it can yield so unstable results? Is it simply the complexity of ARMA-GARH models which did not allow for better functions to be out there yet?

Comment: As far as I know, it is the `forecast` package and its author who are ahead of the others, not `rugarch` and its author being behind. I guess it is not too difficult to build the safeguard in in `rugarch` and other packages, but probably not so many people are aware of the prevalence of the problem against which the safeguard is needed.

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting. I have a really off-topic question but I thought you were probably the person most likely to know this: Do you have a trick to export GARCH-output to TeX? So far, I have met none and I know people that have done this in a very time consuming way. 

This question has also already been asked on stackoverflow, but no one knew an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312645/how-to-export-garch-output-to-latex

Comment: Would love to help you with this, but I do not know how to do this myself...

Comment: I found a solution and posted it there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312645/how-to-export-garch-output-to-latex/62357990#62357990

Comment: Cool! Thanks for letting me know.